# mongodump - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

When trying to do a mongodump we get this error:

```
$mongodump --host <host> -db <db> -out C:/ --username username --password password
```

The output is:

```
Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating m
etadata file C:\590690e1231230279214b1319f2\_Join:users:_Role.metadata.json
: open C:\590690e1231230279214b1319f2\_Join:users:_Role.metadata.json: The
filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

**Is there a work-around for this** when using a Windows OS machine? This db is a database of a [parse-server](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mongoDB 3.2, the `--archive` option is [introduced](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--archive), which allows writing dump into a single file instead of a directory, e.g.:

```
$mongodump --host <host> --db <db> --archive <archive_file_name> --username <username> --password <password>
```

Note that the same option is used to specify the dump file to restore when using `mongorestore`.

Answer (score 1):

good day.. as you can see in the error your command is trying to dump _Join:users:_Role Collection which is invalid filename to mongodb, first rename those collection and try to dump again, or else try to dump the collections one by one. make sure not to include those invalid filename unless you rename them

Comment: I have the same problem, but it use to work before. Also, these classes are Parse.com/parseserver classes and aren't meant to be renamed.

Comment: This is not even an option as @JulienAltieri mentioned _ prefix is a must for parse-platform.